# Return SQL to Generic List Automatically

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a function that connects to a database and extracts data.

The data is returned into an Expando Object.

I usually then convert the expando object into a class, with linq statement on a dynamic line however, I was wondering if I had a class with all of the fields in my SQL code, is there any way for the system to automatically map to each field in my class?

I.e.

```
public List<CLIENTALL> FullTableClients()
{
  const string abstractStatement =@"SELECT * FROM CLIENT WHERE CLINO = '0000001'";

  var sqlStatement = new SqlStatements(abstractStatement, _reportingBackOffice.GenerateTables);

  var data = _reportingBackOffice.ExecuteQuery(sqlStatement);

  var name = (from dynamic line in dataArray
              select new CLIENTALL()
              {
                ClientNumber = line.?????
                //normally I would write line.ClientNumber
                }).ToList();

  return name;
}
```

As you can see above, I need a way for to almost reference the field name in the class and use that as a variable when I assign from line?

Thanks,

David

Comment: I am not sure about the Expando object but normally we do it with AutoMapper , is that what you looking for?

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) `Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. ` - There are entire books written about ORM.

Comment: Agree with Jamiec, you should do a little bit of research before asking at SO. There are tons of technologies that map tables to classes and viceversa. For instance, you could google _Entity Framework_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a linq2SQL datacontext you can write:

```
const string abstractStatement = @"SELECT * FROM CLIENT WHERE CLINO = '0000001'";
using (var db = new MyDataContext())
  var col = db.ExecuteQuery<CLIENTALL>(abstractStatement).ToList();
```

It will map the columns form the SQL statement to the properties in `CLIENTALL`